# python file on practise excercise gives error " TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" in two different instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

#this is my code, I don't understand

[link to picture of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sGFv.png)

#how would I make the int 18 callable using the right functions. I am trying to achieve something that determines your age and eligibility to vote.

thank you, kind regards everyone!

Comment: You assigned `age` to `print`, so it hid the built-in `print` function. Don't name your variables same as built-in types and functions.

Comment: print(age) not print=(age)

Comment: get rid of the equal sign in print=(age)

Comment: add source code as text not a picture

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra `=` after `print` on line 3.

By the way, you can copy and paste the code in your question instead of using a screenshot. You can then surround the code with three backticks(```) in the beginning and end to format the text as code.

Comment: you need take a read ! https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp

Answer (score 0):

your print method is off I believe. You don't want to assign age to print and that is what you're doing when you have print = (age). To print you want print(age)